# selecting a math sign from cell and using in vba formula

Tags: excel, string-concatenation, vba

I stumbled across a new puzzle called "go figure!" in the local paper. I can't find anything on it currently on the web but it is similar to sudoko but with math operatives.
You are given a list of numbers to use and you have to fill in the blanks.
For example:
The first row would be _ / _ + _ = 10

I have in cell D4 a / and cell F4 a +

My vba code has

```
Dim OPR11, OPR12, as String
```

then further down I have

```
OPR11 = Cells(4, 4).Value
OPR12 = Cells(4, 6).Value
```

So in this case OPR11 = / and OPR12=+

Next I set up an array with the numbers and do a next for loop  as follows:

```
For Each rng3 In vArray
  For Each rng2 In vArray
    For Each rng1 In vArray
 If rng1 & OPR11 & rng2 & OPR12 & rng3 = R1A Then
  DO CODE
 end if
    next rng1
  next rng2
next rng3
```

As many fo you can see, my `If` function isn't working. Evidently, I can't `CONC` the mathamatical operators into the formula as it stands and have it work.

How should i better do this to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: You mean you can get a set of numbers and set of operators like "+,-,!,^"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `Evaluate()` to calculate a formula expression.

For example

[image]

turn on the Immediate Window with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

and run the code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Dim c4 As Range
    Dim d4 As Range
    Dim e4 As Range
    Dim f4 As Range
    Dim g4 As Range

    Set c4 = Cells(4, 3)
    Set d4 = Cells(4, 4)
    Set e4 = Cells(4, 5)
    Set f4 = Cells(4, 6)
    Set g4 = Cells(4, 7)

    Dim answer As Double
    answer = Evaluate("=" & c4 & d4 & e4 & f4 & g4)

    Debug.Print "The formula evaluates to: " & Evaluate("=" & c4 & d4 & e4 & f4 & g4)

    Cells(4, 9) = answer

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't even know about that command. Now that you pointed it out, I did a search and found this: [link](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52372). It even states on that page, "1. Converts string math expressions to values". Very informative, and definitely something worth remembering. Thanks

Comment: can I indulge an explanation and a correction of the following: `If Evaluate("=COUNTIF( Range(Cells(4, c21), Cells(735, c21)), Cells(r1, c11)") < 1 Then` ? I can't quit figure out where the " should all go. By the way, c21,c11,and r1 are badly named variables in the code.

Comment: @BillFlippen youre correct. `c21` is not a valid number. When using `cells(x,y)` you need both `x` and `y` to be numbers. When using `Range()` then `C21` wrapped in double quotes would make sense on its own.

Comment: What I meant was that c21 is not a cell name but rather a variable that means in my mind column 2 entry 1 . SO let me re write this for clarification `IF Evaluate ("=COUNTIF("& RANGE(CELLS(4,var1),CELLS(735,var1)) & "," & CELLS(var2,var3) & ")")` appears to be correct but I still get type mismatch error.